# Converting area from degrees to square kilometres using OpenLayers geometry?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, area

I get a multypolygon from my web service and want to calculate the area of that polygon. I was trying to use this piece of code:

```
var poly = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon(poligon);
var area = geom.getArea();
```

But that returns the area in square degrees.  The projection is EPSG:3243.
I then tried to use

```
OpenLayers. Layer. SphericalMercator
```

But that didn't help me a lot.

Is there any other solution or some other hint?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var poly = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon(poligon);
var area = geom.getGeodesicArea();

var kmArea = area / 1000000;
```

Reference:
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.getGeodesicArea

Comment: I think you need to divide by 1e6 to get square km not multiply by 1000.

Comment: Not sure, but wouldn't it be divide by 1000 since the function returns square meters? I definitely goofed by multiplying by 1000 but what i meant was divide by 1000.

Comment: there are 1000m in a Km so 1000*1000 sq m in a sq km

Comment: +1 Okay i follow  you, excuse my math disorder, but then it would be area / 1000000?

Comment: that's what I said :-)

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know it is not possible. Some references to it:

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27851

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=9&f=85&t=132922

You will need to transform to meters first.